# Set full layout of Image in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to set two images in two different layouts.

The resolution size of the image: 986 * 569.

Layout with .50 weight

Something like below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bluebg"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/AmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".50">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/am"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horibreak1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/PmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".50">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pm"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the image is not stretched to full layout. How to fix this?

I get something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb1OV.png

Comment: for that you have to stretch that image accordingly,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
1.)<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bluebg"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/AmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:background ="@drawable/am"/>
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horibreak1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/PmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background ="@drawable/Pm"
    android:layout_weight=".50"/>
</LinearLayout>

2.) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bluebg"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/AmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/am"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:scaletype ="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horibreak1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/PmLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pm"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:scaletype ="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, if you know the file path of image, then

Your path:

```
File photo= new File(imagepath);
```

then:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(photo);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,350, 350, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

set image view property as

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```